# PG admin shows empty data output

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

My query is apparently correct and I should get outputs given the fact that the data output board shows the column and the number of values per column, but it doesn't display the values.
Any help is welcome, looking forward to solving this, thank you!

A screenshot for clarity:

[image: PG admin returns empty data output]

Comment: Either your join doesn't return anything or you don't have any rows with `district = 'california'`. Maybe you need `district = 'California'`?

Comment: It seems it's returning something given the fact that below the column district there's written "character varying (20)" and similar information below the column email. Buuuut, actually the issue was the case, I tried with 'California' and it worked, thank you!

Comment: That's the structure of the result (as defined by your SELECT list) - but apparently no rows are returned which strongly indicates that either your WHERE or your JOIN don't find anything to return

Answer (score 0):

try to use explain (shift+f7) button to see how many rows ur query match